# How to get blocked SMSes in android phone using query?

Tags: android, sms, blocked

I am trying to get blocked SMSes from my android phone using query? (I blocked one phone number, I got some messages from blocked phone number)

```
Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String s = "1",;


Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, "locked=?", new String[]{s}, 
null);
```

I expected blocked messages ,but cursor is empty